# Can not run 'yum update'

Tags: yum

I am a new user. When I run yum update, I encounter the issue:

```
Error: Package: glibc-2.12-1.212.el6_10.3.i686 (updates)
           Requires: glibc-common = 2.12-1.212.el6_10.3
           Installed: glibc-common-2.17-55.el6.x86_64 (installed)
               glibc-common = 2.17-55.el6
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6.x86_64 (centos6u3)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.80.el6
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.212.el6.x86_64 (base)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.212.el6
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.212.el6_10.3.x86_64 (updates)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.212.el6_10.3
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 2 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
glibc-2.12-1.209.el6_9.2.i686 has missing requires of glibc-common = ('0', '2.12', '1.209.el6_9.2')
glibc-2.17-55.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with glibc-2.12-1.209.el6_9.2.i686
```

Answer (score 1):

These packages require to be all at the exact same version:

- glibc i686 (32 bit version)
- glibc x86_64 (64 bit version)
- glibc-common (common code)

so in this case it seems like you are trying to install `glibc-commong.i686` at version `2.12-1.212.el6_10.3`. However you already have a more recent x86_64 version installed (`2.17...`). So to fix the installation you have two options:

- find a repository where you also get a more recent version for `glibc-commong.i686`
- tell `yum` to downgrade your `glibc-commong.x86_64`: `yum downgrade glibc-common-2.12-1.212.el6_10.3.x86_64`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
yum --skip-broken
yum clean all
```